# How to remove extra space from top and bottom of svg image in IE11

Tags: html, css, svg

I am using SVG to display result and want to align item in the center of the defaultSize container. In chrome, the svg image is getting properly centered but in IE 11 extra space is getting displayed at top and bottom of svg image and vertical scrollbar is getting displayed as well.

```css
.svgImage {
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.defaultSize svg {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left;
    transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="defaultSize">
  <div class="svgImage">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 1435.01 184.01">....</svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

SVG displayed in chorme: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyndu.png

SVG displayed in IE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/srdfN.png

Answer (score 0):

You need display: block; on your svg.

Comment: No changes after adding display:block on svg